# Delete/Update Configurable Product from php

Tags: api, shopping-cart

I am trying to delete a configurable product in my cart wiht shoppingCartProductRemove with Api SOAP v2, but the api return

> Please specify the product's option (s)

There is a way to add/remove/update the product from cart with the id of the cart (quoteId) with an PHP?

I have a mobile app where show your cart and then update/delete an product from the cart via php. I have the Configurable Product id, the quoteId, the attributesOfchild, and the childId.